# Late subscription renewal real-time developer notification with Google Play Billing Library 2

Tags: android, subscription, play-billing-library, renewal

When using [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes)(*GPBL*) **2** in the client, the **first renewal** [real-time developer notification](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications)(*RTDN*) arrives 22 hours **after the subscription expiration**.

Such gap might cause denial of our services for the user.

With *GPBL* *1.2.2* in the client, the renewal *RTDN* arrives 2 hours prior to the subscription expiration.

### Steps to reproduce:

Use any *GPBL* version 2+ in an android client app. (Tested with *GPBL* 2.0.3, 2.1.0, 2.2.0)

### 1) Purchase a subscription on Google Play (in the client)

Tested with:

- 7-day trial *Paid* subscription.
- 5min, 15min, 30min *Test* subscriptions (For *Test* subscriptions the *RTDN* arrives 10 seconds after the expiration when using *GPBL* 2, as opposed to 2 minutes before the expiration when using *GPBL* 1.)

5min *Test* subscription used in the following example:

### 2) Verify the purchase (backend)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/[packageName]/purchases/subscriptions/[subscriptionId]/tokens/[token]
```

- Response:

```
{
  "expiryTimeMillis": 1584703350967, // "2020-03-20T11:22:30.967Z"
  "autoRenewing": true,
  "priceCurrencyCode": "CZK",
  "priceAmountMicros": 159990000,
  "paymentState": 1,
  "orderId": "GPA.3399-3829-9285-87596",
  "acknowledgementState": 0
}
```

### 3) Acknowledge the purchase (backend)

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/[packageName]/purchases/subscriptions/[subscriptionId]/tokens/[token]:acknowledge

{
  "developerPayload": null
}
```

- Response 200 (empty body)

### 4) Wait for a renewal notification (backend)

- Received at 1584703361173 epoch millis `// "2020-03-20T11:22:41.173Z"`

```
{
  "countryCode":"CZ",
  "developerPayload":"",
  "kind":"androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "orderId":"GPA.3399-3829-9285-87596..0",
  "priceCurrencyCode":"CZK",
  "autoRenewing":true,
  "expiryTimeMillis":1584703770967, // "2020-03-20T11:29:30.967Z"
  "startTimeMillis":1584702935111, // "2020-03-20T11:15:35.111Z"
  "priceAmountMicros":159990000,
  "paymentState":1,
  "purchaseType":0
}
```

The notification arrived 10 seconds later than the original expiration time!

The only difference I'm aware of is the different *GPBL* version in the Android client and the purchase acknowledgement call which is required by the *GPBL 2*.

Only the first renewal notification is delayed. Subsequent renewal notifications are on-time, 2 minutes prior to each expiration.

### Question:

Is there anything to do to get the first renewal notification before the expiration?

Thanks for any hint or advice!

Comment: Have you been able to solve your problem? I think I have a similar case: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66716996/13558952). So maybe your solution could help me too.

Comment: Hi, we have implemented the renewals according to this Google statement: "Developers should not solely rely on RTDN to determine expiration. Developers should call the Google Play Developer API (server API) at the expiryTimeMillis, even if RTDN has not sent a notification."