# Google Billing API: Shortly after subscription purchase, subscription expired is triggered, directly followed by subscription renewed

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, in-app-purchase, play-billing-library, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am using Firebase Cloud Functions to handle the back-end process for In-App-Purchases. If I purchase a subscription (on Flutter/Android client), the purchase flow works without problems. However, when the first Renewal happens, I get first a Real Time Developer Notification that the Subscription has Expired, and around 50 Seconds later I get a new notification that the subscription got renewed.

Detailed Process is as follows:

---

**1.** Purchase subscription on Client (at the moment in internal testing Mode)

> --- Start of Google Cloud Logging Events (hh:mm:ss):

**2. 00:00:00** - Notification Subscription Purchased Triggered
(empty function, only prints to console)

**3. On Client**, InAppPurchaseConnection purchaseUpdatedStream (Flutter) is triggered, Client sends data to back-end and Cloud Function verifyPurchase is triggered.

**4. 00:00:03** - verifyPurchase function execution started

**5. 00:00:05** - Status 200 response received

**6. 00:00:06** - Acknowledge Response received (Status 204)

**7.** *Until here all is good and I can see the correct data in Firestore DB*

**8. 00:04:08** - Notification Subscription Expired Triggered
(back-end revokes subscription, leaving the user without any additional services she/he purchased)
Subscription Status response:

> {
> "startTimeMillis":"1616129098091",
> "expiryTimeMillis":"1616130591517",
> "autoRenewing":false,
> "priceCurrencyCode":"KRW",
> "priceAmountMicros":"2900000000",
> "countryCode":"KR",
> "developerPayload":"",
> "cancelReason":0,
> "userCancellationTimeMillis":"1616130398607",
> "orderId":"GPA.3391-[...].3",
> "purchaseType":0,
> "acknowledgementState":1,
> "kind":"androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
> "obfuscatedExternalAccountId":"q[..]3"
> }

**-> Cancel Reason here states: 0. User canceled the subscription (which is not the case)**

**-> AcknowledgementState is 1: Acknowledged**

Please see: [REST API REF Resource: SubscriptionPurchase](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions)

**9. 00:05:01** - Notification Subscription Renewed Triggered
From here on everything works as expected and the user receives the services she/he paid for.

**10. ~ 16. 00:10:01 ~ 00:35:20** - Notification Subscription Renewed Triggered 4x times, then cancelled and expired (expected behaviour)

> --- End of Google Cloud Logging Events.

---

```
export const verifyPurchase = functions.region("asia-northeast3").https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const {sku, purchaseToken, packageName, purchaseType} = data;
  const userId: string = context.auth?.uid ?? "";
  functions.logger.log(`USER ID: ${userId}`);

  let result = 0;

  try {
    await authClient.authorize();
    functions.logger.log("START TO CHECK SUBSCRIPTION OR ONE TIME PURCHASE");
    if (purchaseType === PurchaseType.subscription) {
      const subscription = await playDeveloperApiClient.purchases.subscriptions.get({
        packageName: packageName,
        subscriptionId: sku,
        token: purchaseToken,
      });
      functions.logger.log("SUBSCRIPTION BEING PROCESSED");
      if (subscription.status === 200 && subscription?.data?.paymentState === 1 || subscription?.data?.paymentState === 2) {
        functions.logger.log(`SUBSCRIPTION STATUS: ${subscription.status}`);

        if (!subscription.data.linkedPurchaseToken) {
          const subscriptionData: any = {
            "transactionId": purchaseToken,
            "userId": userId,
            "expirationDateMs": subscription.data.expiryTimeMillis,
            "disabled": false,
            "platform": "android",
            "receipt": data,
            "rawData": subscription.data,
          };

          await admin.firestore().collection("subscriptions").add(subscriptionData).then(
              async (value) => {
               [...user Data being updated on DB...]
          );

          const acknowdlegeResponse = await playDeveloperApiClient.purchases.subscriptions.acknowledge({
            packageName: packageName,
            subscriptionId: sku,
            token: purchaseToken,
            requestBody: {
            },
          });
          functions.logger.info(`ACKNOWLEDGE RESPONSE SUBSCRIPTION: ${JSON.stringify(acknowdlegeResponse)}`);**
        } else {
          await subscriptionChange(purchaseToken, userId, data, subscription);
        }

        result = subscription.status;
      }
    } else {
      const oneTimePurchase = await playDeveloperApiClient.purchases.products.get({
      [...part for one time purchases...]
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
    functions.logger.error("verifyPurchase ERROR");
    functions.logger.error(e);
  }
  functions.logger.log(`RETURN RESULT: ${result}`);

  return result;
});
```

So I don't exactly understand why step 8 (expired) happens.
I would appreciate any help.